# Opengl texture on quad

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

This is the content of my Texture class:

```
public int id;

public Texture(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteBuffer buf = null;
    int tWidth = 0;
    int tHeight = 0;

    try {
        PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(inputStream);
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*decoder.getWidth()*decoder.getHeight());
        decoder.decode(buf, decoder.getWidth()*4, PNGDecoder.TextureFormat.RGBA);
        buf.rewind();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        ErrorHandler.handleError("Failed to load image", exception);
    }

    id = glGenTextures();
    glActiveTexture(id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, tWidth, tHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

This is how i render:

```
    glActiveTexture(background.id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, background.id);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 4*18);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

and this is the fragment shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 textureCoordinate;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;

void main() {
    outputColor.rgb = vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    outputColor += texture2D(texture_diffuse, textureCoordinate);
}
```

**What do i do wrong?** The texture coordinates passed to the shader program are 100% correct (i checked). But i still get a white quad.

Note: i use [this](http://fastpng.sourceforge.net/) png decoder.

**EDIT:**
I printed out floats for every 4 bytes to the console, and i got 0.00.00.00.0.... Doest that mean that the texture is loaded incorectly, or the informations is stored to the buffer in a different format?

Answer (score 2):

Your fragment shader looks wrong - you set a white colour and add the value from the texture, so it will clamp to white. Just do something more like this

```
void main() {
    outputColor.a = 1.0f;
    outputColor.rgb = texture2D(texture_diffuse, textureCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. My fragment shader sets the color of all triangle to white, and then adds the texture on it. The tried that many times, and everything wored fine. Anyway, i tried your code to be sure, and i got a back screen. That's because the quad was absolutely transparent.

Comment: Nope. I think that the quad is transparent, because there's nothing to add to it... How can i check if the png decoder gets the right information?

Comment: @visDEVion: The quad cannot be transparent unless you are using blending.

Comment: @NicolBolas if you don't set any color to the quad, you cannot see it. Doesn't that make him transparent?

Comment: or it's black, and i can't see it because the background is black?

Comment: yes.. It's black... But that is not the problem! I'll edit the question

Comment: @visDEVion: "*if you don't set any color to the quad, you cannot see it. Doesn't that make him transparent?*" No. You get undefined behavior. Your particular hardware and driver made it black, but it could have been anything.